# C# converting type double to float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I'm new to C#, and I can't work out why I'm getting the following error on these lines of code.

> "error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
float rightEdgeOfFormation = (float) transform.position.x + (width * 0.5);
float leftEdgeOfFormation = (float) transform.position.x - (width * 0.5);
```

I thought writing (float) was the cast?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think it's just your brackets. `float rightEdgeOfFormation = (float) (transform.position.x + (width * 0.5));`

Comment: Just remember, when you write somethink like `0.5` it's interpreted as `double` value, if you want it to be `float` add `f` to the end of number like `0.5f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A type cast has the highest precedence of all other operations.  Therefore, `(float) transform.position.x` is evaluated before `+ (width * 0.5)`.  However, `(width * 0.5)` is a `double` expression, because the constant `0.5` is a `double` constant.  (You should have used `0.5f` if you wanted it to be `float`.)  And when adding a `float` and a `double`, C# always "promotes" the `float` to `double`.  So, the result of `float + double` is a `double`, which is then not assignable to a `float`.

To fix it, either put the entire expression in parentheses before casting to `float`, or make your `0.5` a `float` constant by writing it as `0.5f`.

Answer (score 4):

You're multiplying by 0.5, when you're using floats you need to put `f` at their end.

This will work:

```
float rightEdgeOfFormation = transform.position.x + (width * 0.5f);
float leftEdgeOfFormation = transform.position.x - (width * 0.5f);
```

Comment: No problem - it happens to everyone, be sure to accept my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Best answer. No need to cast anything, or use the ugly Convert.ToSingle() I've seen in one answer. Always think to use right suffix on your number.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
float rightEdgeOfFormation = (float) (transform.position.x + (width * 0.5));
float leftEdgeOfFormation = (float) (transform.position.x - (width * 0.5));
```

you are just casting transform.position.x not the entire expression & something else in the expression is causing the calculation to be done as a double.

Answer (score 1):

```
float rightEdgeOfFormation = (float)transform.position.x + ((float)width * 0.5F);
float leftEdgeOfFormation = (float)transform.position.x - ((float)width * 0.5F);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float

Comment: For me it's not clear that `width`, `transform.position.x` and `transform.position.y` are no doubles. That's the reason why I put a cast in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just your brackets. `float rightEdgeOfFormation = (float) (transform.position.x + (width * 0.5));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
float rightEdgeOfFormation = Convert.ToSingle(transform.position.x + (width * 0.5));
```

float leftEdgeOfFormation = Convert.ToSingle(transform.position.x - (width * 0.5));

Comment: And what do you think about to cast it to a string before to call Convert, just to get sure to have the worse possible solution ?